# Visual Studio 2013 issue - even after reinstall

Tags: visual-studio-2013

No matter what I do, with the Windows forms C#, I'm constantly getting this error

http://prntscr.com/7owfk2

When trying to add any text boxes. That's on a clean project. I don't know what to do. I cannot use VS2013 because of that error.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Insn't an instance of the application running ? (possible a hidden process)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by scrapping Visual Studio 2013 and installed Visual Studio 2015 RC. It's not really a fix, but it resolved my issue.